# how to present UIAlertController located in another UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am getting the following error:

> Attempt to present  on Check5GHz: whose view is not
>   in the window hierarchy!

SplashViewController:

```
let check5ghz = Check5GHz()
check5ghz.determineIf5GHz()
```

Here is what Check5GHz looks like:

```
class Check5GHz: UIViewController {

func determineIf5GHz()-> Void{

 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

So it seems like the problem is that one ViewController is trying to launch an UIAlertController found in another ViewController which it does not seem to allow. But I need to have this UIAlertController appear from many different ViewControllers. Could you recommend another way?

Comment: Put your function in an extension to UIViewController.

Comment: Create a class for that so that you can use it anywhere.

Comment: You can present a controller only after the presenting `viewController` has loaded.

Comment: iOS7?  Seriously?

Comment: @monekypox121 You are simply creating an instance of your `Check5GHz` class which is of class `UIViewController` but you are not loading this `viewController` on screen and then directly trying to present a controller on top of it. That's not how this works.

Comment: It is unclear, but I assume that view controller `Check5GHz` can be discarded.

Comment: Your problem is that you're calling `self.present` when `self`'s view is not present in the view hierarchy. If you want to present the alert in `Check5GHz`'s view wait until it's loaded. (ie. `viewDidAppear`)
If you want to display it on `SplashViewController` then either move the presentation logic to `SplashViewController` or pass it to `Check5GHz` as an argument and do the presentation on it. (ie. `splashScreenVC.present(..)`)

Comment: There are two possible scenarios and @monkepox121 should clarify this. `Check5GHz` is view controller with a real purpose other than presenting the alert. Or, it's only purpose is to show this alert and OP is misunderstanding how view controllers work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension UIViewController {
    func determineIf5GHz()-> Void{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: 
        UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then in any of your view controllers do this:

```
self.determmineIf4GHz()
```

Comment: but this means that I will have to add this extension to dozens of ViewControllers... is that right ?

Comment: No. Since you are adding the extension to UIViewController, all your view controllers automatically get the function.

Comment: @ryantxr in a sense you answered part of his question but @monekypox121 will still not be able to present an alert because the `viewController` has not been segued/loaded

Comment: I am assuming that SplashViewController is loaded correctly.

Comment: @ryantxr From his code, it seems he is creating another `viewController` class and calling a method in it. It doesn't matter what state the `SplashViewController` is in.

Comment: Right. Using the extension, it no longer necessary to create that other view controller.